# Error running simple jar with MQ classes for Java

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jar, ibm-mq

I'm very beginner of `Websphere MQ classes for Java` programming.
I've decided to follow this way to write a small application able to connect and read messages from a queue through TCP/IP.

following this guide: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fja10410_.htm

At point 4 it is suggested to test `Websphere Client` installation (Version: 7.0.1.8) on windows command prompt using:
 `java -Djava.library.path=library_path MQIVP`
where 'library_path' for me is "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib"

The application runs and I have proceeded writing a simple program with `Eclipse IDE` here the code:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;

public class MQtestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main");

        new MQtestMain();
    }

    public MQtestMain(){

        System.out.println("MQtestMain");

        MQEnvironment.hostname = "my.host.name";
        MQEnvironment.channel = "my.channel";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;

    }

}
```

It has nothing to do but it is just a test to be sure that everything is correctly set.

I have set a custom library with both 'com.ibm.mq.jar' and 'com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar' from "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib" and no error are reported at compile time.

Running the application from `Eclipse` it correctly prints out "main" and "MQtestMain" on console.

Therefore I have proceeded to export it: File > Export > Runnable Jar 
setting 'Library handling' to 'Package required libraries into generated JAR'

Unfortunately if I run the program from windows command prompt: `java -jar MQtest.jar`
here the result:

```
main
MQtestMain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/ResourceException
        at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:576)
        at MQtestMain.<init>(MQtestMain.java:21)
        at MQtestMain.main(MQtestMain.java:14)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

First and second line are correct but I really don't understand the following errors

---

**update:**

I try to give you more information: 
As I've said running the application from its main `class` file there are no problems, while execute it from the `jar` file it seems not able to find the IBM libraries.
I have created a personal library in `eclipse` named "MQ classes for Java" containig the two jar packages used by this application.
here the content of the project `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/MQ classes for Java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Is there a way to link the correct libraries to the runnable jar in order to launch it form every machine with WMQ Client installed?

---

**Solution:**

The errors, due to some dependencies not found, have been solved including **all** the `IBM classes for Java` `jar` files into the `WMQ Client` folder instalation ("C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib")

Comment: Which version of WMQ client is installed?  (What is displayed when you type `dspmqver` or `"C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\dspmqver"`?)

Comment: here the result: `Name:        WebSphere MQ`
`Version:     7.0.1.8`
`CMVC level:  p701-108-120224`
`BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)`

Comment: I think you might have better luck replacing the [tag:command-prompt] tag with the [tag:eclipse] tag. Although you've phrased this as an MQ problem, it seems to me that what you are really saying is "I have a program that works in Eclipse but when I attempt to create a runnable jar that includes dependent libs I get `ClassNotFoundException` at run time." That sounds to me more like an Eclipse issue than an MQ issue. Of course we can address it as an MQ issue if you want and you can definitely get it to work by fiddling with `CLASSPATH` and `-Djava.library.path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

These errors are due to some dependencies not found;
they could be solved including **all** the `IBM classes for Java` `jar` files into the `WMQ Client` folder instalation ("C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib")

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this just by adding javax dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use java.library.path like you did for MQIVP test or set your CLASSPATH to contain the MQ JAR files.

Comment: I've tried to follow your suggestion with the command: `java -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib" -jar MQtest.jar` obtaining the same error.
Therefore I suppose I wrote the wrong path.
Anyway I thought a JAR file is a "full pack" with all the files it needs for run, is it wrong?

If I execute: `java MQtestMain` from the bin folder of my eclipse project it runs correctly, but I need to run it from a different machine.

Comment: The other machine needs to have installed the WMQ client code from IBM. There is no redistributable license or package for IBM's WMQ code and it's not supported if you just grab or package the jar files.

Comment: Ok there are no problems for me to install the `WMQ Client` in all the machines I'm going to run the application, but I prefer to use a "single-file" program (like a JAR) instead of a sereies of classes (consider the case I would have a graphic interface on a separate `.class` file). Which should be the correct way to run the executable JAR?